# Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism iff $f[\overline A] = \overline {f[A]}$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism iff $f[\overline A]  = \overline {f[A]}$, I know how to prove that $f$ is continuous iff $f[\overline A]  \subset \overline {f[A]}$, but how can I complete?

Comment: What else is needed besides continuity?

Comment: I assume you're given that $f$ is a bijection too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f:X\to Y$ is homeomorphism, then $f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$ by continuity of $f$. Say $g$ is an inverse of $f$. Then using continuity of $g$, $\overline{f(A)}=fg(\overline{f(A)})\subset f(\overline{gf(A)})=f(\overline{A})$

The other direction requires $f$ to be bijection. Indeed, if this assumption is not included, we have the following example:

Take $X=\mathbb{N}$ equipped with indiscrete topology, and take $Y=\mathbb{S}=\{0,1\}$, Sierpinski space equipped with topology $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\mathbb{S}\}$. Now define $f$ by

$$f(n)=0 \;\;\forall n$$

For any nonempty $A\subset \mathbb{N}$, $\overline{A}=\mathbb{N}$, and clearly $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{S}$, so that

$$f(\overline{A})=f(\mathbb{N})=\{0\}=\overline{\{0\}}=\overline{f(A)}$$

If you do have an assumption that $f$ is bijection, then the rest is easy.

Comment: If $f$ is bijection, How would be the rest?

Comment: @Idonotknow Just mimic what I did in first part of the answer. Basically, you want to show that if $g$ is an inverse, for all $B\subset Y$, $g(\overline{B})\subset \overline{g(B)}$. But this is easy once you note that if $f$ is a bijection, then any subset $B$ of $Y$ must be of the form $f(A)$ for some $A\subset X$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is continuous iff $\forall A \subseteq X: f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$

$f$ is closed iff $\forall A \subseteq X: \overline{f[A]} \subseteq f[\overline {A}]$ (if $f$ is closed, for every $A\subseteq X$: $f[\overline{A}]$ is closed and contains $f[A]$ hence also $\overline{f[A]}$, and if the inclusion holds for all $A$, and $C \subseteq X$ is closed, then $f[C] \subseteq \overline{f[C]} \subseteq f[\overline{C}] = f[C]$, so $f[C]$ is closed and $f$ is a closed map)

So if $f$ is a bijection it's a homeomorphism iff $\forall A \subseteq X: f[\overline{A}] = \overline{f[A]}$ is a direct consequence.